# C Programming Optimization and Processor Extensions

Tags: c, performance, optimization, processor

I've got a C programming assignment which involves optimizing the code as much as possible. I've had a bit of a read about this on the Internet already and found things like using `case` over `if`, pass by pointers instead of value, etc.

What I'd like to ask about is why knowing what processor extensions are available, can help me to optimize my code? I know that SSE and AVX are available on the machine but what exactly does that mean to me as a programmer?

In relation my above question, I found the [Intel Intrinsic Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) which I think is related to the processor extensions. Are there any advantages in terms of performance in using these functions over other C functions. e.g. would using `_mm_sqrt_ps` from `xmmintrin.h` be faster than `sqrt` from `math.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have per CPU optimized libraries (SSE, AVX etc), and call something like _may_i_use_cpu_feature() to dynamically determine what feature is available at runtime and load the "best" implementation for the CPU.

For portable code you want to use sqrt() - and some runtime libraries have optimized implementation that are good enough. If you want full control and maximize performance on a specific platform, and don't care about portability, you can write hand optimized assembly (or use intrinsics).

Most performance is gained by better algorithms anyways...